# How do I find the first and last occurrence of a string in a row?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that has a few thousand rows where I need to identify the first and last occurrence of "Y" for each row. (These characters are tied to specific dates depending on the column they fall into). I have to find the start and stop of these characters because it will give me the start and stop dates of each task. So far I have tried this:

```
Public Sub import_gbs()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim gbs_wb As Workbook
Dim gbs_bg As Worksheet
Dim gbs_drivers As Worksheet
Dim bg As Worksheet
Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim date_array() As String
Dim x As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim switch As Integer
Dim start_position As Integer
Dim stop_position As Integer    

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.TransitionNavigKeys = False

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set bg = wb.Sheets("Current EDGE")
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
Set gbs_wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\SOME PATH HERE\")
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityByUI
Set gbs_bg = gbs_wb.Sheets("CC Input")
Set gbs_drivers = gbs_wb.Sheets("Drivers")
Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary '''

dict.Add "SU YN Start", gbs_drivers.Cells(9, 5).Value
dict.Add "SU YN Stop", gbs_drivers.Cells(9, 6).Value
dict.Add "EPMP1 YN Start", gbs_drivers.Cells(10, 5).Value
dict.Add "EPMP1 YN Stop", gbs_drivers.Cells(10, 6).Value
dict.Add "EPMP2 YN Start", gbs_drivers.Cells(11, 5).Value
dict.Add "EPMP2 YN Stop", gbs_drivers.Cells(11, 6).Value
dict.Add "RC YN Start", gbs_drivers.Cells(12, 5).Value
dict.Add "RC YN Stop", gbs_drivers.Cells(12, 6).Value
dict.Add "ON YN Start", gbs_drivers.Cells(13, 5).Value
dict.Add "ON YN Stop", gbs_drivers.Cells(13, 6).Value
dict.Add "FU YN Start", gbs_drivers.Cells(14, 5).Value
dict.Add "FU YN Stop", gbs_drivers.Cells(14, 6).Value
dict.Add "DB Lock YN Start", gbs_drivers.Cells(15, 5).Value
dict.Add "DB Lock YN Stop", gbs_drivers.Cells(15, 6).Value
dict.Add "CO/Reporting YN Start", gbs_drivers.Cells(16, 5).Value
dict.Add "CO/Reporting YN Stop", gbs_drivers.Cells(16, 6).Value

i = 2
For x = 3 To 9543
    If gbs_bg.Cells(x, 25).Value > 0 Then
        start_position = gbs_bg.Range("AI" & x & ":" & "AP" & x).Find(what:="Y", lookat:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlNext).Column
        stop_position = gbs_bg.Range("AI" & x & ":" & "AP" & x).Find(what:="Y", lookat:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column

        Select Case start_position
        Case 35
            gbs_bg.Cells(x, 65).Value = dict("SU YN Start")
        Case 36
            gbs_bg.Cells(x, 65).Value = dict("EPMP1 YN Start")
        Case 37
            gbs_bg.Cells(x, 65).Value = dict("EPMP2 YN Start")
        Case 38
            gbs_bg.Cells(x, 65).Value = dict("RC YN Start")
        Case 39
            gbs_bg.Cells(x, 65).Value = dict("ON YN Start")
        Case 40
            gbs_bg.Cells(x, 65).Value = dict("FU YN Start")
        Case 41
            gbs_bg.Cells(x, 65).Value = dict("DB Lock YN Start")
        Case 42
            gbs_bg.Cells(x, 65).Value = dict("CO/Reporting YN Start")
        End Select

        Select Case stop_position
        Case 35
            gbs_bg.Cells(x, 66).Value = dict("SU YN Stop")
        Case 36
            gbs_bg.Cells(x, 66).Value = dict("EPMP1 YN Stop")
        Case 37
            gbs_bg.Cells(x, 66).Value = dict("EPMP2 YN Stop")
        Case 38
            gbs_bg.Cells(x, 66).Value = dict("RC YN Stop")
        Case 39
            gbs_bg.Cells(x, 66).Value = dict("ON YN Stop")
        Case 40
            gbs_bg.Cells(x, 66).Value = dict("FU YN Stop")
        Case 41
            gbs_bg.Cells(x, 66).Value = dict("DB Lock YN Stop")
        Case 42
            gbs_bg.Cells(x, 66).Value = dict("CO/Reporting YN Stop")
        End Select

        i = i + 1
    End If
 Next x
```

So this is working for me most of the time. There are some really weird instances on a handful of rows where there is a "Y" present in column 35, but the find misses it and picks up the next instance of "Y" in that row. Out of the 7,000+ rows, this only happens a handful of times and always in column 35 (but most of the time it finds the "Y" in that column of that row if it is there). This obviously messes up my dates for those rows. I have no idea what it could be. I have tried debugging by checking the length and value of the cell where the "Y" is that the find is missing. But that returns as 1 and with the value of "Y". I've tried switching between searching in values and formulas, that doesn't work either.

So I need to find a new way to find the occurrences. I was thinking that since I know vba does recognize the length of the value of each cell correctly, I could build off of that. But I'm not sure how to begin. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This would be a lot easier to figure out with some sample data and the expected result. Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59289437/edit) to provide this?

Comment: `InStr` gives you first, `InStrRev` gives you last.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to create small for loop to go through your 8 columns of data (AI to AP) and find first and the last occurrence of "Y" and check if that is very time consuming. But with manual calculation and screen updating off it should not be so long.
Below you can find simple sub ready for testing.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim t#: t = Timer
    Dim wbs As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim startposition As Integer
    Dim endposition As Integer

    Set wbs = ActiveSheet


    With wbs
        For x = 1 To 7000
            startposition = 0
            For col = 35 To 42
                If .Range(.Cells(x, col), .Cells(x, col)).Value = "Y" And startposition = 0 Then
                    startposition = col
                ElseIf .Range(.Cells(x, col), .Cells(x, col)).Value = "Y" And startposition <> 0 Then
                    endposition = col
                End If
            Next col
        Next x
    End With

    Debug.Print Timer - t

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

My score is 0,57s on empty sheet. You can analyze that code and maybe implement that loop. For x loop is just a simulation of your 7000 rows.